# Openfire: Can the user rejoin the chatroom after been deleted from the chatroom?

Tags: openfire

After using using openfire rest api to remove target user out of the chatroom, can the target user rejoin the chatroom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To avoid the behaviour, you must grant the `OUTCAST` (= banned) `AFFILIATION` to the user kicked out.

Check out official specs :

- [terminology](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#terms)
- [Affiliation](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#affil)
- [Ban user](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#ban)

Seems REST API it's a bit confusing about role and affilitions, however official spec:
[Delete user from Chat Room](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#delete-a-user-from-a-chat-room)